How to set up a local W3C HTML validator server and use it in Rails testing
I would like to incorporate W3C VNU validator for HTMLs to my Rails app in the test environment.
I use the w3c_validators gem for Rails as the wrapper for the W3C validator. In default, it uses the validator on the original W3C website. But, it would be bad to connect to the W3C website so many times in repeated tests (and understadably, you would be eventually refused with 429 "Too Many Requests").
So, I would like to set up the local VNU validator and use it to test my Rails app. How can I do it?
Specifically, my test environment is on macOS.

First, you need to install the VNU app in your local environment.
This answer in Stackoverflow gives a collection of websites/articles to help.
For macOS Homebrew, the following would be the simplest:
brew install vnu

Check out if the installation was successful:
rehash
vnu YOUR_DOC.html
  # => should output the HTML validation result

Also, I assume Java (Ver.8 or later) is installed in your environment.
Second, check the path to vnu.jar in your enbironment.  If VNU has been installed with Homebrew, it is likely to be
$HOMEBREW_CELLAR/vnu/<VERSION>/libexec/vnu.jar,
where <VERSION> can be obtained with vnu --version .  If the environmental variable HOMEBREW_CELLAR is not set, your Homebrew environment is likely to be set up for Intel, and it is probably /usr/local/Cellar
Let us call the path <JAR_PATH>
Third, launch the local VNU server (in a separate terminal from the one where you are testing your Rails app) with either of the following.  vnu --help prints extensive information for further detail.
java -cp <JAR_PATH> nu.validator.servlet.Main 8888
java -Dnu.validator.servlet.bind-address=127.0.0.1 -cp <JAR_PATH> nu.validator.servlet.Main 8888

As of vnu-23.4.11, the default address is http://0.0.0.0:8888/ .
However, vnu warns that it will be changed to http://127.0.0.1:8888/ .  So, you may as well set it explicitly for now so that it is more future-proof.  Here, let us assume you use the latter, http://127.0.0.1:8888/
Finally, the following will validate the currently-displayed HTML in your Rails controller test (for the Article model, for example).
Your Rails Gemfile must contain:
group :test do
  gem 'w3c_validators'
end

Your controller test (in minitest):
require "test_helper"
require 'w3c_validators'

class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get index" do
    get articles_url
    assert_response :success
    validator = W3CValidators::NuValidator.new(validator_uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/")
    assert_empty validator.validate_text(response.body).errors
  end
end

Note that the forward slash '/' at the tail of the URI seems indispensable.
To add, this gist may be of some help as a wrapper for the three lines above and more to print more helpful information, including where the validation fails.
